# Listview as a log file

Tags: c#, listview

Hi. I have a Windows form application. After I do something, what I want is to put updates in the `Listview`. More like a log file. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    listView1.GridLines = true;
    listView1.FullRowSelect = true;

    //Add column header
    listView1.Columns.Add("Import Status", 100);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Price", 70);
    listView1.Columns.Add("Date", 70);

    //Add items in the listview
    string[] arr = new string[4];
    ListViewItem itm;

    //Add first item
    arr[0] = "product_1";
    arr[1] = "100";
    arr[2] = "10";
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
    listView1.Items.Add(itm);

    //Add second item
    arr[0] = "product_2";
    arr[1] = "200";
    arr[2] = "20";
    itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
    listView1.Items.Add(itm);
}
```

How can I Add items to the `ListView` without 'hardcoding' them? Any suggestions? How can I do that every `Button.Click`, it can add rows with some data in it?

Comment: You could get data from a database.. ?

Comment: no,it doesn't involve any database.

Comment: ok - an XML file perhaps? Data doesn't "just appear" - what data is it you want to add?

Comment: From where are you getting data to put in listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   How can I Add items to the ListView without 'hardcoding' them?
```

Code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.GridLines = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Import Status");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Price");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Date");      
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem LVI = new ListViewItem(txtstatus.Text);
        LVI.SubItems.Add(txtPrice.Text);
        LVI.SubItems.Add(txtDate.Text);
        listView1.Items.Add(LVI);
    }
```

UI

[image]

Comment: Can the rows be retained? because after closing the program, the rows are gone

Comment: If you want persistent data, just store the data(files,DB) before application close,then retrieve it on Form_Load.

Answer (score 1):

Globalize your these two lines to allow your access in every method of your class:

```
string[] arr = new string[4];
ListViewItem itm;
```

Now create a `button click` event and put your code in it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            arr[0] = "product_2"; //you can get these values from textboxes if you are taking input from user
            arr[1] = "200";
            arr[2] = "20";
            itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
            listView1.Items.Add(itm);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

hi there :) you could use a datagridview instead of the listview control.

all you have to do is to define an own dataset or add a dataset control
to your project. u just need to add your three columns to a new datatable in there.
then:

- add that dataset to your form, it will appear in your form code
- set the datasource of the datagridview to the added dataset

now you can add new datarows to the datatable and they will appear in the datagridview automatically. the good thing is, you have to define your table layout once and the designer will generate you a custom datarow type, what you can use.

my experience told me, that this way is more comfortable than using listview. the main thing is, u can LINQ over the datatable if you want to process data from there in other
context. i used listview before, but since datagridview in combination with dataset, everything is better ;)

sincerly,
ceth

Comment: can I use data grid view without connection to SQL?

Comment: sure you can :) a dataset/datview as datasource in a datagridview is just a virtual database in your memory and can be handled LIKE a real database or just a collection of datarows in a datatable

Comment: Can the rows be retained? because after closing the program, the rows are gone

Comment: you can use _System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer_ to serialize the data into a xml file for storage. when restarting your app just deserialize the xml and reload the data into the datatable.